# Check resolver existance by Router event in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

Is it possible to know if route has resolvers or not with `router.events`?
I tried to find it with:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(e => {
  console.log(e);
})
```

But it seems that there is no information about resolvers in router events. I need this for progress bar. Maybe `ActivatedRoute` can be useful in this case? But where exactly should i look? `activateRoute.snapshot.data` is always empty object

I also tried:

```
private isRouteHaveResolvers() {
    let firstChild = this.activatedRoute.firstChild;
    while (firstChild && firstChild.firstChild) {
      firstChild = firstChild.firstChild;
    }
    return firstChild && firstChild.routeConfig && !!Object.keys(firstChild.routeConfig.resolve).length;
  }
```

But it doesnt work properly. For example for this case:

```
{
        path: 'edit',
        component: EditComponent,
        resolve: {
          data: resolverData
        },
        children: [{
          path: 'activity/:activityId',
          component: ModalComponent,
          outlet: 'modal',
        }],
      }
```

For this route `activity/:activityId` it return true

Comment: means you want to use `ActivatedRoute` but you are not able to where to use this, right?

Comment: No, I mean it has a lot of nested properties and it is hard to understand where to look it for.